# Why does my laptop not pick up a specific WiFi signal?

Tags: wireless-networking

So, I have a work laptop, a Dell xps 13 9360, it works great. At least it did until it decided to no longer pick up the WiFi signal at work. Very strange, because every other device in the building connects no problem, and the laptop works fine on all other networks.
After several months, it suddenly connected to the work signal! Hurray. 
Now it won't pick up the signal again. I think it coincides with a power surge we had in the building, which played havoc with WiFi for all devices, but they all seemed to get fixed, except this laptop. 
I'm convinced there is nothing wrong with the laptop, and it is the network blocking this specific device. But, how would I check that? And what can I do to fix it. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Approximately how many devices are there on the work WiFi? It's possible the wireless router your work is using is leasing IP addresses for way too long. Try going to Run or command prompt and typing `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /renew` - hitting enter after each command and see if it will let you pull a new IP address.

Comment: @maef that is unlikely to be the cause because were that the problem rebooting or turning WIFI off and in wluld fix it.

Comment: Trouble is, we're a retail store, and if I go messing around with IP addresses it could upset all the tills and cause more issues, which I don't need.